# Change the speed of /dev/urandom

Tags: performance, shell, random, generator

Is there a way to control the speed of /dev/urandom

For example, I have such generator of binary sequences :

```
grep -ao "[01]" /dev/urandom|tr -d \\n
```

I need to make it more slow, 100 symbols at second, 1000 symbols at second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pv` to (among other things) rate limit data from a pipe:

```
grep -ao "[01]" /dev/urandom | tr -d \\n | pv -q -L 100
```

Here I use `-L` as in "limit" to get an output rate of at most 100 bytes per second. The `-q` is there to suppress debugging output from `pv`. For 1000 bytes per second you could use `-L 1000` or `-L 1k` instead.

Comment: If you have `xxd` installed I think the following, based on your answer, will waste fewer bytes from `/dev/urandom`.


`cat /dev/urandom | xxd -b | cut -f2-7 -d' ' | tr -d ' '\\n | pv -q -L 100`

Answer (score 1):

if you have perl, for example can make an small script e.g. `cps.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep);
local $|=1;
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    print $_;
    usleep(100000);
}
```

and run:

```
grep -ao "[01]" /dev/urandom | perl cps.pl
```

play with the usleep time for get the right speed. Maybe want implement the grep part with perl too.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes qw( usleep);

open my $rfd, "<:raw", "/dev/urandom" or die "$!";
my $buff;
local $|=1;
while() {
        read ($rfd, $buff, 1);
        next unless $buff =~ /[01]/;
        usleep(10000);
        print $buff;
}
close $rfd;
```

and simply run `perl cps.pl`

**Added:**
If you don't need cryptographically safe randoms you can use the next one-liner:

```
perl -MTime::HiRes -e '$|=1;while(1){print int(rand(2)); Time::HiRes::usleep(10000)}'
```

Comment: A little bigger and not pure bash, but the script works perfectly. Second script version doesn't work natively on my Linux Mint machine "Can't locate IO/handle.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ...".

Comment: Confirmation for second script, works well without grep, like it.

Answer (score -1):

This will probably vary wildly depending on processor, but fun to try

```
#!/bin/bash    
microsleep ()
{
  for (( y=0; y<$1*50; y++ ))
  do
    :
  done
}

tr -cd 01 </dev/urandom | while read -n1 b
do
  printf $b
  microsleep 1
done
```

Result

```
$ timeout 1 microsleep.sh > log

$ stat -c%s log
1011
```

Comment: got: tr: Illegal byte sequence

Comment: works for me. just one problem : proposed script doesn't handle well microdelays to produce 1000bit/sec, but it still interesting solution.

Comment: Pretty nice. instead of "1" after microsleep, it could be $1, so You could precise the delay from the outside of the script. Need #!/bin/bash in the beginning in another case, it throws an error.